# Column Delimiter while exporting data from table using expdp - oracle

Tags: oracle

Instead of creating a stored procedure & using util package in Oracle to write each record from a table to a flat file in desired column delimited way (i.e. '#|'), can i use expdp to perform the same thing ??

This will help in extracting data in a much faster way.

Please suggest.

Comment: `expdp` is not intended to write flat files.

Answer (score 1):

As I see the docs: [Oracle® Database Utilities 11g Release 2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm), expdp is unable to do formatting.

But you can use external tables for database unloads.
First you should create a directory:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY mydir AS 'C:\MyDir'
```

Then grant access to it:

```
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY mydir TO myuser;
```

Finally in one step create an external table and export the result of a query into it:

```
create table mytable (
    col1 varchar2(100), col2 varchar2(100)
  ) organization external (
  type oracle_loader
  default directory mydir
  access parameters (
    records delimited by newline
    fields terminated by "#|"
  )
  location('myfile.txt')
) as select col1, col2 from anothertable;
```

Here is a good link to read more details about external tables: [Oracle® Database Administrator's Guide
11g Release 1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables013.htm)